# How find the smallest floating point number in a .txt file?

Tags: python, file, floating-point, python-3.11

Here is the question:

> Suppose that you have a text file that contains a list of floating-point numbers, one number per line. Write Python program that will search through the file and find and print to the console the smallest number.

We can't use functions like `.readlines()`, `with`, `try`, `inf`, or `None`.

This is what I have and I am stuck.

```
in_file = open("floating-point.txt", "r")


def get_smallest_float():
    count = 0
    for line in in_file:
        num = float(line)
        if count == 0:
            if num > 0:
                smallest = num
                count = count + 1
        elif count == 1:
            if num < smallest:
                num = smallest
                count = count + 1
    in_file.close()
    return smallest

get_smallest = get_smallest_float(in_file)
print(get_smallest)
```

Comment: If `count` is not 0 or 1, your function stops doing anything...

Comment: Also, why are you comparing `num > 0`?  Negative numbers are a thing.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing an actual *problem.* You say you're stuck but don't actually state what the problem is with your current code. That's an important thing to include, don't you think? :-)

Comment: I'm having trouble get my program to find the smallest floating point in the in_file. And I can't use anything that I haven't learned in class.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that your function doesn't accept any parameters, but then you attempt to pass the function "in_file".

Comment: Can you explain why you have those constraints? What other standard Python functionality are you not allowed to use? You say "We can't use functions like..." so presumably there are others

Comment: "And I can't use anything that I haven't learned in class." --> that is something you know, but is not generally known to others.  Post your constraints if "We can't use functions like .readlines(), with, try, inf, or None." is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few logic and syntax errors, but this seemed to work.
I removed the positive number test. The problem stated smallest number, not smallest absolute value. The assignment of the new minimum was also reversed. This solution does not handle cases of a tie.

```
in_file = open("floating-point.txt", "r")


def get_smallest_float():
    count = 0
    for line in in_file:
        num = float(line)
        if count == 0:
                smallest = num
                count = count + 1
        elif count > 0:
            if num < smallest:
                smallest = num
                count = count + 1
    in_file.close()
    return smallest

get_smallest = get_smallest_float()
print(get_smallest)
```

and the diff:

```
diff -u before after
--- before  2023-11-03 22:23:58
+++ after   2023-11-03 22:23:19
@@ -6,15 +6,15 @@
     for line in in_file:
         num = float(line)
         if count == 0:
-            if num > 0:
                 smallest = num
                 count = count + 1
-        elif count == 1:
+        elif count > 0:
             if num < smallest:
-                num = smallest
+                smallest = num
                 count = count + 1
     in_file.close()
     return smallest
 
-get_smallest = get_smallest_float(in_file)
+get_smallest = get_smallest_float()
 print(get_smallest)
```

Given this floating-point.txt:

```
1.0
1.1
1.2
0.9
-.01
.01
```

the result is -0.01

Given the floating-point.txt with these:

```
1.0
1.1
1.2
0.9
-.01
.01
-.02
-.001
```

the result is -0.02

Answer (score 0):

The constraints are bizarre. However, given those constraints then it's as simple as:

```
for i, fv in enumerate(map(float, open("floating-point.txt"))):
    lo = min(lo, fv) if i else fv #type: ignore

print(lo) #type: ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect something more like:

```
for line in in_file:
    num = float(line)
    if (count == 0) or (num < smallest)
        smallest = num
        count = count + 1
```